# Calculating probabilities for beam splitter setup

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-optics, interferometry

let us consider the following setup of beam splitters: single photons enter beam splitter A with R/T ratio of 50:50 and split into two paths A1 and A2. A1 enters beam splitter B and A2 enters beam splitter C. beam splitter B splits into two paths B1 and B2 with R/T ratio of 85:15 and beam splitter C splits into two paths C1 and C2 with R/T ratio of 95:5. using mirrors we then combine B1 and C1 using beam splitter D (one way glass where all of C1 is transferred and all of B1 is reflected) into one beam and send it to Detector1 and also combine B2 and C2 using beam splitter E (one way glass where all of C2 is transferred and all of B2 is reflected) into one beam and send it to Detector2. assuming the lengths A1=A2=B1=B2=C1=C2 and we create phase difference of X in path B1 and phase difference Y in path B2.

1. how would we calculate the probability of a photon to reach Detector1, P(D1), and Detector2, P(D2)?
2. are there phase differences X,Y that could give us P(D1)=35 and P(D2)=65? if not how do you explain that physically and equationwize?
   [image: BS Setup]

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your text is inconsistent with the figure, your "one way glass" can't exist in QM. An element that would fully reflect the beam into the same port into which another beam is transmitted would be non-unitary, unless the two beams were distinguishable in some auxiliary degree of freedom (like polarization).